# Converting 'curl -F' to Python requests

Tags: python, curl, python-requests, restheart

I'm trying to do a multi-part form upload with "requests" in python.  I can upload the file, but it never loads the additional fields that are typically passed through the -F flag with curl.  The curl command I'm trying to mimic:

```
curl -v -u user:password -X POST -F 'properties={"filename":"maurizio.png"}' -F "file=@maurizio.png" 192.168.59.103:8080/testdb/mybucket.files
```

The requests code is:

```
url = "http://192.168.59.103:8080/testdb/mybucket.files"
content_type = "multipart/form-data"

params = {"filename":"maurizio.png"}
params["_id"] = "test_hash_1234" 

data = open('maurizio.png','rb').read()

files = {'file': ('maurizio.png',data,content_type,params)}               
request = requests.post(url,files=files,auth=('user','password'))
```

This file is loaded into restheart api for mongodb.  The "_id" is a special object id that the database uses to reference the object.  I need to specify that document field in additional to other document fields like the filename.  The file is uploaded into Mongo's blob datastore called gridfs.  I can upload the data and the additional document fields with curl, but the "requests" code above only uploads the data and not the additional document fields. I need those additional fields for querying.

Can somebody help me convert the -F flag into something that equivalent to python's requests module? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [example in the manual](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/quickstart/#post-a-multipart-encoded-file):

```
files = {'file': ('report.xls', open('report.xls', 'rb'))}
r = requests.post(url, files=files)
```

Note that the first you should pass the file and not the data (you don't need to `read()` the content of your file, you just need to pass the file object)

Answer (score 0):

By the way, there is also a [Github repository](https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart-python-test) which shows some basic examples of accessing RESTHeart with Python.

The objective was to show how to make simple RESTful calls using Python and the [requests library](http://www.python-requests.org/en/latest/), please, feel free to contribute your pull requests adding more cases, or just have a look at the existing tests if they can help you.